# How to add dependency with dynamic lifetime

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection

In my NuGet package, I want to add a method that receives the `ServiceLifetime lifetime` parameter and adds a service to the DI container using it.
I have implemented it with the code

```
public static void AddProvider(this IServiceCollection services, ServiceLifetime lifetime = ServiceLifetime.Singleton)
{
    var descriptor = new ServiceDescriptor(
        typeof(IEnvironmentVariableProvider),
        typeof(EnvironmentVariableProvider),
        lifetime);
    services.Add(descriptor);
}
```

Is there a more concise method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't really a (much) more concise way to do what you want. What you have is fine.

If you look at the source for ASP.NET's `ServiceCollectionExtensions`, it has a private method that looks a lot like yours (of course it takes two type parameters, where you've "hardcoded" them to your specific types.

If you find yourself making more `Add` type methods and don't mind rolling another extension method, you could create an extension method like

```
public static class MyServiceCollectionExtensions
{
    public static void AddDynamic<TInterface, TClass>(
        this IServiceCollection services,
        ServiceLifetime lifetime = ServiceLifetime.Singleton
    )
    where TClass : class, TInterface
    where TInterface : class
    {
        services.Add(new ServiceDescriptor(typeof(TInterface), typeof(TClass), lifetime);
    }
}
```

and then your call would be a little bit more concise.

```
public static void AddProvider(this IServiceCollection services, ServiceLifetime lifetime = ServiceLifetime.Singleton)
{
    services.AddDynamic<IEnvironmentVariableProvider, EnvironmentVariableProvider>(lifetime);
}
```